# adding 2 keys for react-select search filter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-select, react-select-search

I am using react select in my react app same like below

---

when i use '***labelKey={'staffName'}***' to get the key from api to search.
so when I use like above its showing the output perfectly.

what I am trying to do is need to search  another key ***lanId*** also.
so I tried to add like this.

---

***labelKey={'someid' || 'stafName'}***

---

when **adding 2 keys** output is showing only for the first one. I need to find a way to add **2 keys** for the filter search part . could anyone able to help me on this ??

```
 <Select
                                    name="selectStaf"
                                    placeholder='Select Staf'
                                    value={selectStaf}
                                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                                    options={stafDataList.stafsInfo}
                                    multi={true}
                                    labelKey={'someid' || 'stafName'}
                                    valueKey={'stafId'}
                                    isLoading={loadingee}
                                    onInputKeyDown={(e)=>{this.filterStafApi(e)}}
                                />
```

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, the `||` operator would return the first item unless it is falsy (`undefined`, or `null`, or `0` or `''`).

You might want to try a string concatenation like this:

```
labelKey={`${someid} ${stafName}`}
```

Comment: i am using react-select plugin  so when I added your code the button part totally hidden , not sure labelKey supports 2 keys is there any way to add 2 keys in react select
this is the plugin https://react-select.com/advanced

Comment: ok, I did assum that `labelKey` was used to search, but reading the documentation of `react-select`, it seems that `labelKey` is just not a property 
If you are looking for a way to add "key words" in the filtering of the "search", you might want to implement a custom `filterOption` function, no?

Comment: yeah correct need to add a filter option function . could you able to help me with that ?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/4rwrpwv8n7?file=/example.js you can help me here @Xavier

Comment: need you show out put when user trying to search using both name id

Comment: Sorry I totally missed to answer this thread >< 

The solution is here: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandboxer-example-forked-ye8bq1?file=/example.js

It seems that when using the default options keys (`value` and `label`), react-select will automatically search on both ;-)